# Нужно объединить метки "профиль-участника" и "страница-учётной-записи"

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, метки, синонимы-меток, мета

Оказалось, что сейчас есть пара идентичных меток на мете:

- [профиль-участника](/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%84%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0) (100 вопросов)
- [страница-учётной-записи](/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b0-%d1%83%d1%87%d1%91%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b8) (27 вопросов)

Вторая метка уже содержит синоним [profile-page](/questions/tagged/profile-page) и это не даёт сделать метку [профиль-участника](/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%84%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0) основной обычными средствами.

> [image: Не удалось предложить синоним]

Вероятно, модератор может справиться с этим.

Comment: А что если перенести 27 вопросов из одной метки в другую, а потом попросить администрацию просто убить лишнюю?

Comment: @aepot это не эффективно. Если метка появилась, то велика вероятность, что она появится вновь. Ну и само ручное перевешивание меток - тоже неэффективно, и, более того, приведёт к поднятию вопросов в списке.

Comment: Вы теперь модератор, можете синонимизировать метки?

Comment: @Зонтик готово!